QGIS 3.34.7 Single sided buffer changes - creating unexpected result
On QGIS 3.34.7 LTR, if you try to "Single sided buffer" a self closing line/full encircle (yellow line), with a value let's say 2 meters it will create a polygon inside and the edge where single sided buffer needs to be will be empty with that exact specific value (green arrow).
It should create a polygon starting from the line, with a specific width of the mentioned buffer value (blue arrow).


Solution:
To identify self encircled lines you can extract by expression with the following formula:
$geometry = make_polygon($geometry) AND num_points($geometry) = num_points(make_polygon($geometry))

This expression checks if the geometry of the line can be converted into a polygon and ensures that the number of points in the original line matches the number of points in the resulting polygon. This helps to ensure that the line forms a closed shape by itself.
Then you can use "Split line by maximum length" where you can split the line wherever you want, in order to close that encirclement and create a proper "Single sided buffer".
